# Number of votes for a related question comes out of block

Tags: bug, design

Number of votes comes out of `div` block:

[image]

Because `width` is set to `20px` in styles:

```
#sidebar .answer-votes {
    width: 20px; /* <- Here */
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #eee;
    color: #888;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px 6px 0 0;
}
```